Add a "log" for a single function
I need to debug some legacy code and I only want to print some information to a file that will not disturb any other places in the codebase. The most crude way I have found so far is something like:
def my_func():
    f = open('/tmp/log.txt', 'a') # help with logging stuff
    f.write('Here is my crude local logger.')
    # some code
    logger.log('Hello') # our 'Normal logger' that goes to Splunk
                        # so I don't think I can modify this 
                        # safely without side-effects?

However, I like all the 'extra' stuff that the logging module adds in, such as line numbers, time, functions, etc. What might be the best way to add in a local logger to do what a normal logger might do?

"What might be the best way to add in a local logger to do what a normal logger might do?" What differentiates a "normal" logger from a "local" logger, other than where it is initialized, and what is stopping you from using the logging module inside the function?

python has a logging module, you can look at the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

@iBeMeltin OP is clearly aware of this module

@DeepSpace ah I did not even realize he mentioned it in the question

@DeepSpace the "normal logger" is configured (levels, filter, etc.) to log only to Splunk, and I do not want to change something that may have global effects on the logger.

@David542 Create a new logger inside the function def f(): ... new_logger = logging. ... with (most likely) its own handlers

It is possible to create a local logger using the very same logging module:
import logging

def my_func():
    local_logger = logging.getLogger('my_func_logger')
    # set custom handlers on local_logger, maybe even control creation with a function
    # or some env vars

    # some code

    local_logger.log('Hello')


thanks, though when I try using this approach it ends up changing things globally. For example, when I set a level on the logger it cascades to my global logger...

@David542 It shouldn't be the case if done correctly, maybe add a [mcve]. Are you sure you are passing a different string to logging.getLogger?

thanks, with the unique text string it worked.

The logger is still your friend. You can customize it to your liking; I'll be referring to Python's how-to guide for this.
One part of making your own Logger is configuring the Formatter. One such way of doing this does not pose too much of a challenge:
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s') is one example.
The Formatter itself is simple. The constructor has three optional arguments: the string format, a date format string, and the style indicator.
The Formatter is where you should turn for your line numbers and other information you wish to put.

Just a note on the creation:

Note that Loggers should NEVER be instantiated directly, but always through the module-level function logging.getLogger(name). Multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object.

